# Displaying multiple raster datasets in Netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo, raster

It's my first time working with Netlogo. I'm trying to display the following raster files. One is a land use map and the other, an elevation map. The land use map displays fine. However, I'm unable to view the elevation data when I inspect my patch values.The elevation data shows 0 which is not the case.The rasters themselves are fine, I've double checked in R and ArcGIS. The projections match, etc. I need both the maps to run my submodels. At the moment, I'm only able to display the lulc map using the setup procedure. However I'm not sure if the elevation data is also being read by Netlogo. Is there a way I can fix this? I'd like to be able to display both the maps using a button, maybe?

```
    extensions [gis]
    globals [lulc elevation-map]
    patches-own [ class elev]



   to load-gis

   clear-all

   set lulc gis:load-dataset "lulc.asc"
   set elevation-map gis:load-dataset "elev.asc"

   gis:set-world-envelope-ds gis:envelope-of lulc
   set elevation-map gis:create-raster gis:width-of lulc gis:height-of lulc gis:envelope-of lulc 



   gis:apply-raster lulc class 
   gis:apply-raster elevation-map elev

   ask patches  [

   if class = 0[ set pcolor blue ]
   if class = 1 [set pcolor green]
   if class = 2[ set pcolor red ]

   ]


   end
```

Comment: Just to follow up: I get the following error when I change the order of the maps. 
Extension exception: All factories fail for the operation "border"
error while observer running GIS:APPLY-RASTER
  called by procedure LOAD-GIS
  called by Button 'load-gis'